# Aspectj annotations

Tags: java, aspectj

I have written an aspect aj file as shown below for my java class

```
pointcut printMessage(String name) : call(public static String myhobby(..)) && args (name);
     before(String name) : printMessage(name) {
            System.out.println("Aspects: "+ name);

     }
```

And I try to write the same aspect file using annotations as shown below

```
@Before("call(* myhobby(..)) && args(name)")
         public String callFrom(String name) {
           System.out.println("value is: " + name);
         }
    }
```

But it shows

```
 the attribute value is undefined for the annotation Before
```

Can any one tell me how to resolve this

Comment: Do you want to execute the method callFrom(String name) just before  calling of the method String myhobby(..) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define a point cut before the myhobby(..) method using the following code :

```
//Method before which point cut needs to be set
@Pointcut("execution(* package.name.ClassName.myhobby(..))")
    public void pointCutFunction() {

    }

@Before("pointCutFunction()")
    public Object myAdvice(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint)
             {
Object arr[]=proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
 System.out.println("value is: " + arr[0]);

}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It shows cannot resolve ProceedingJoinPoint..what  do I have to import

Comment: import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;

Comment: In my case i have added dependency for aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar

Comment: It worked..Thank u..If I exported it as a jar and when I used this jar in another java file and calling the function in jar(exported jar) for which I wrote aspects...will the advice for that function run?

Comment: `@Before` advice do not need `ProceedingJoinPoint`, but just `JoinPoint`. The former are for `@Around` advice.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Chaotic again. You have not even posted the right error message. For your pointcut the error message should be:

```
This advice must return void.
```

And that is exactly what must be changed. Do you ever read error messages?

```java
@Before("call(* myhobby(..)) && args(name)")
public void callFrom(String name) {
    System.out.println("value is: " + name);
}
```

No need for any `getArgs()` overhead.

Comment: @kriegaex...Thank u Mr.Genius...I know how to read the error message and I posted the error what I got... because I didnt import the import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*; ...

Comment: No, sorry, that is just not true. Then the code would not even have compiled and you would have gotten `Before cannot be resolved to a type`.

Comment: Then the code you posted is not the code you compiled. I copied and pasted it into my IDE and tried. Or you have more aspect code and the error message you copied comes from one of your other bugs. Anyway, my code snippet works, feel free to use it.